# Is Huawei a pentaphtong?

Tags: diphthongs, triphthongs

Is the word **Huawei** a pentaphtong?

Comment: Short answer--no. But whether something is a _whatever_-thong is language-dependent. You should include the language (Mandarin?) in the question. And what makes you think it might be a 'pentaphthong'?

Comment: It looks like Pinyin indeed, so Mandarin, but it'd be good to specify it anyways. Please expand on your question. :)

Comment: @musicallinguist: It has five vowel sounds togheter.

Comment: OP may be asking about the word in English. As a proper noun for a big electronics company it's uttered by millions of non Mandarin speakers every day all over the world.

Comment: @hippietrail: What is OP?

Comment: @sergiol: On internet forums OP means "original poster". In this thread that means you (-:

Comment: Hi, Sergiol.   Please identify the source language and find out which of the five vowels is syllabic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean 华为; unsimplified 華為; pinyin Huáwéi. This word consists of two syllables, with a diphthong in the first syllable and a triphthong in the second syllable; whatever-phthongs are always within the same syllable. So in this case 2 + 3 does not equal 5.

Comment: The acute accents make more clear that Huá- and -wéi are separate syllables

Comment: w- is always syllable-initial in Pinyin. The non-initial spelling for the coda /uei/ is –ui.

Comment: So, is it spelt uá-uí?

Comment: Νο. Ιt is spelt huáwéi, but this represents two syllables: huá and wéi. The Pinyin system uses the letter w only at the beginning of a syllable. You can observe that in Chinese script it is written with two characters: 华 and 为.

Comment: Knowing nothing of Mandarin I had always assumed the second syllable had initial /w/. What happens at hiatus between the two syllables? Can someone provide a phonetic representation of the word, thanks?

Comment: @fdb: Maybe I asked the wrong question. The real question is: is it SPOKEN uá-uí?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I would have answered your question earlier if I could get this site to accept proper phonological notation, but I have not found a way to do so. In hua, the u is a non-syllablic glide and a is a full vowel. In wei you have the full vowel e preceded by an onglide (non-syllabic u) and followed by an offglide (non-syllabic i). The acute accents are tone markers.

Comment: Depending on one's definition of a diphthong (and a triphthong), I think it could be argued that the nucleus of the first syllable is just a monophthong (with [hw] in the onset) and that of the second is a diphthong (with [w] in the onset).  Either way, nowhere near a 5-thong.